# Live USB or Live CD not booting?

Tags: 12.04, live-cd, live-usb, boot-failure

Either it's Live USB or Live CD, Ubuntu 12.04 won't boot on my old laptop.

It gives an error with this message all the time:

```
"This kernel requires the following features not present on the CPU : PAE"
```

Is there anything I could do? I would prefer fresh installing the 12.04 instead of upgrading from 11.10.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would like you to download non-pae kernel of ubuntu-12.04. [Click here](http://people.canonical.com/~diwic/12.04-nonpae/ubuntu-nonpae-12.04-desktop-i386-beta.iso) to download the image file of the cd.

Comment: You could also try out ubuntu 10.10 or 11.04 and do an upgrade from there.

Comment: you're the man! it worked perfectly. I had to do a partial upgrade after doing the fresh install. thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Per ashutosh's instructions/answer and link above, downloaded *ubuntu-nonpae-12.04-desktop-i386-beta.iso* -- must be burned to DVD+R (not CD-R), as iso-image size is 735.2 MB. But then the DVD+R boots fine, installing 12.04 on an old Sony Viao laptop now.  Thank you!

Comment: BTW, why the decision to drop the old non-pae kernel for distros, especially as it's seeming to cause problems on older non-pae laptops & desktops for so many Ubuntu users?  With all the controversy (largely unwarranted) about Unity, 12.04 and subsequent releases do *not* need the additional headaches and issues.  Don't drop that support for non-pae kernels!

Comment: Installation on my old Sony Viao laptop worked just fine with the non-pae (beta) iso-image.  Thank you again!